# Flutter extraction doesn't work \flutter\bin\cache was unexpected at this time

Tags: flutter

I downloaded the sdk from here https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install/windows

Extracted inside C:\Program Files

I get the following error

```
 \flutter\bin\cache was unexpected at this time.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs mention (sadly not prominent enough)

> do not install Flutter in a directory like C:\Program Files\ that requires elevated privileges).

So this is probably the cause.